# How to split sentence by separator to two parts only

Tags: python

I have example sentence with '_' separator:

```
s = "This_is_some_sentence_ID"
splited = s.split('_')
print(splited)
```

This give array like ['This', 'is', 'some', 'sentence', 'ID']

But how can i get two parts like ['This_is_some_sentence', 'ID']?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [rsplit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rsplit):

```
In [3]: s = "This_is_some_sentence_ID"

In [4]: splited = s.rsplit('_', 1)

In [5]: print(splited)
['This_is_some_sentence', 'ID']
```